# Is there a centralized database of all stars?

Tags: star, data-analysis, star-catalogues

Is there a centralized database for all stars, sourced from Gaia and other missions?

Comment: There is a list of contemporary star catalogues in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_catalogue#Full-sky_catalogues_(in_chronological_order)  However, bear in mind that "There are, however, billions of stars resolvable by 21st century telescopes, so this is an impossible goal; with this kind of catalog, an attempt is generally made to get every star brighter than a given magnitude"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SIMBAD database hosted by the Centre de Donnees Astronomique de Strasbourg is the closest you are likely to find to a centralised database.

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basicIdent=m33&submit=SIMBAD+search